# JQuery UI Tooltip - wrong placement of tooltip (on the left side of page instead around button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have this piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>My first HTML document</TITLE>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".has-tooltip").each(function(){
            $(this).tooltip({content: "test", items: "button"});
        });
    });

</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <BUTTON class="has-tooltip" style="margin-left: 100px;">First</BUTTON>
    <BUTTON class="has-tooltip" style="margin-left: 200px;">Second</BUTTON>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And something is completely wrong with tooltip - it should appear with styles from jQuery UI but it doesn't, and is wrong placed - it appears, even for button with bigger margin, on the left side of screen (and as I said without any styling, it looks like plain text), even with ,,track" property set to ,,true" it doesn't follow cursor exactly, but still appears on the left side of page and move a little when I move cursor.
I think this is pretty simple example (that code is simplified problem that occurred at my work) and I can't see what am I doing wrong. I will be happy if anybody helps me - thank you in advance.

P.S. Snippet, this is exactly the same behavior as I got in my browser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>My first HTML document</TITLE>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".has-tooltip").each(function(){
            $(this).tooltip({content: "test", items: "button"});
        });
    });

</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <BUTTON class="has-tooltip" style="margin-left: 100px;">First</BUTTON>
    <BUTTON class="has-tooltip" style="margin-left: 200px;">Second</BUTTON>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't linking to the css file correctly.

Replace:

`<link rel="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`

With:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">`

Comment: ...or you are not linking it at all ! :D